# Add images inside frame with loop in tkinter

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Here is a part of my code, which loads images in a LabelFrame based on JSON objects from an external file. The code is inside a function (seems like that plays a role too, who knows).

```
# the black blackboard where images will be stored
black_background = tk.LabelFrame(pivote_tab, width=1340, height=290, bg="black")
black_background.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="E")

# open the .json file
json_file = open('path/to/file.json', 'r')
json_data = json_file.read()

#the init position for image inside the blackboard
live_pc_position = 10

# make a loop for every object inside JSON
obj = json.loads(json_data)
        for i in range(int(len(obj))):
            os = (str(obj[i].get('operating_system')))

            if "Mac" in os:
                img_src = "image/macos_pc.png"
      
            elif "Win" in os and "10" in os:
                img_src = "image/windows_10.png"
            
            elif "Linux" in os:
                img_src = "image/linux_pc_image.png"
            
            else:
                img_src = "image/undetected_pc.png"

            # defining the image based on operating system and store it to the pc_image variable
            pc_image = PhotoImage(file=img_src)

            # adding the computer icon inside the blackboard
            computer_icon = Label(black_background, image=pc_image, bg="black")
            computer_icon.place(x=live_pc_position, y=10)

            # update values so the next image will load to the right
            live_pc_position = live_pc_position + 40
```

The script doesn't make any error, however for some reason only the first image is displayed when there are more images expected to be loaded, because JSON has more objects.

Comment: Since we don't have access to your `file.json`, it would be better if you created an example that used some hard-coded data instead of reading it from a file. There also appears to be an indentation problem. And, you keep overwriting your image variable with a new image.

Comment: Each iteration of the loop changes the value of `pc_image` which affects the previous one. I think adding a `computer_icon.img = pc_image` will prevent the issue.

Comment: @JeffUK: The loop creates a new `computer_icon` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @martineau can you provide an example code? I am not sure if I understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is from @flavio-moraes logically works, however with a mix of the answers I got, I made the final script which fullfills my needs.

```
pc_images=[]
for i in range(int(len(obj))):
    ...
    pc_images.append(PhotoImage(file=img_src))

live_pc_position = 10
for pc in pc_images:
    #create the image
    computer_icon = Label(black_background, image=pc, bg="black")
    computer_icon.img = pc_images
    computer_icon.place(x=live_pc_position, y=10)
        
    # update values so the next image will load to the right
    live_pc_position = live_pc_position + 40
```

Comment: `pc_images.append([...])` should be `pc_images.append(...)` (without `[]`).

Comment: Thanks for the catch, however the problem still persists...

Comment: Is the code inside a function? If yes, then the images are garbage collected.

Comment: It is inside a function actually. I can't make the code outside a function, as I need to refresh the data (which constantly change).

Comment: The indentation of your code can't be correct. Is the second `for` loop really nested inside of the first? It should not be. If it is and this works, then, at best, it's very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with image is not loading in tkinter is almost always related to [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

At every loop you replace the value in pc_image and python garbage collector discards the Tkinter image object. The solution is to storage each Tkinter object in a different variable, which can be done with an object attribute or a list like the example bellow:

```
pc_images=[]
for i in range(int(len(obj))):
    ...
    
    pc_images.append(PhotoImage(file=img_src))
    
    Label(black_background, image=pc_images[i], bg="black").place(x=live_pc_position, y=10)
    
    live_pc_position = live_pc_position + 40
```

Comment: `pc_images.append[...]` should be `pc_images.append(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 tks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was suggesting in my comment. See `ALL CAPS COMMENT`.

```
obj = json.loads(json_data)
for i in range(int(len(obj))):
    os = (str(obj[i].get('operating_system')))
    ...

    # defining the image based on operating system and store it to the pc_image variable
    pc_image = PhotoImage(file=img_src)

    # adding the computer icon inside the blackboard
    computer_icon = Label(black_background, image=pc_image, bg="black")
    computer_icon.img = pc_image  # KEEP A REFERENCE SO IMAGE IS NOT GARBAGE COLLECTED.
    computer_icon.place(x=live_pc_position, y=10)
    ...
```

Comment: Using your solution, only the first image is being displayed. The rest aren't being displayed.

Comment: It was mostly an educated guess. Please provide a [mre] in your question.

Comment: Ok, so I did a mix of your code and the one I answered, now it works. Thank you. I will edit my answer so the others can see it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out. Generally speaking you should almost always create the extra reference. See accepted answer to [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)